# How to import node module with SystemJs?

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I started to use SystemJs. I don't find exact example about how to import a node module? How could I configure SystemJs and how to import this. Because after npm install `import 'package-name' from 'package-name';` it could not find the module.

It would be great if somebody would write an example.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using jspm.io?

Comment: Nope. I use Npm.

Comment: It'd be useful to know about your project. Is it for the web or node? Do you use babel? Can you show us more about it?

Comment: I don't use babel, only use typescript, and SystemJS. I would like to import a node module to ts file.

Comment: You have to say whether you want to load it from a browser or if this is all within node. In the latter case the answer posted below is actually from the official documentation. For browsers there is a question here that has this part actually working: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43983850/544779

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
import nodeModule from '@node/node-module-name' [1]
```

[[1]](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#commonjs)