# Browser test setup: How to make already global SystemJS module available to require('systemjs') of tested code?

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I have code that is fairly system independent and with few system dependent lines of code runs on node.js or the browser. I already managed to setup mocha-based testing so that it works in both those environments, using the same tests and the same code modules. I also managed the browser testing environment to automatically swap calls for those very few system-dependent packages that always call the node.js version for the browser version.

So everything runs, including mocha and sinon and all tests.

Until I decided to use SystemJS not just for running the tests but also within the code itself.

The node.js part still works including the tests. The problem arises when I run the browser tests.

For those I use a index.html file that runs the tests, below it is in its entirety.

Note that this has nothing to do with any later production browser environment, at this early stage all I want is to test the code *(that is purely network and storage based, no GUI stuff whatsoever, using IndexedDB on the browser and websockets on both node.js and browser)* that I already have against the browser.

Key is the line - the only line that is new, everything else has worked for months

```
SystemJS.set('systemjs', SystemJS.newModule(SystemJS));
```

A similar one for `sinon` has worked fine for months, I hoped I could use the exact same method to make the already available `SystemJS` available when a module uses `require('systemjs')`. But it does not work.

This is what the module sees after its `require`:

[image: This is what the module sees after its <code>require</code>]

The actual SystemJS module contents is under that `Symbol(): tt`.

I'm sure the answer is *extremely* simple, but the documentation of SystemJS was of no help to me, which of course may very well be entirely my own fault but that's just how it is, I have to ask after two hours without a result. It took me a while to get the current setup going too, including having to read SystemJS source code, and I figured it all out by myself, but I think this tiny and very specific question might be justifiable for an SO question?

*Just to complete the description of the setup (for those curious): I run it all from WebStorm, directory setup is a usual node.js project with `./test/`, `./src/`, `./lib/`, and of course `./node_modules/`. The html file is `./test/index.html` and I tell WebStorm to "run" it, so WS acts as the webserver for the tests.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Browser Tests</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mochajs/mocha/v3.4.1/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mochajs/mocha/v3.4.1/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <style>
        #errors pre {
            width: 50em;
            margin: 2em 4em;
            padding: 1em;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="errors"></div>
<div id="mocha"></div>
<script>
    /*global SystemJS */
    mocha.setup('bdd');

    // This hack switches the system-dependent components so that require()
    // statements for modules with node.js specific code are exchanged for their
    // browser versions.
    const resolveOrig = SystemJS.constructor.prototype.resolve;
    SystemJS.constructor.prototype.resolve = function (key, parents) {
        return resolveOrig.call(SystemJS, key.replace('-nodejs.js', '-browser.js'), parents);
    };

    // ======================================================
    // RELEVANT SECTION (what I tried)
    // THIS WORKS:
    SystemJS.set('sinon', SystemJS.newModule(sinon));
    // THIS DOES NOT WORK:
    SystemJS.set('systemjs', SystemJS.newModule(SystemJS));
    // ======================================================

    // These are the test scripts in ./test/ that I want to run in the browser
    const mochaTestScripts = [
        // ... ABRIDGED LIST ....
        'crypto-helpers',
        'map-query',
        'object-helpers',
        'storage'
    ];

    SystemJS.config({
        map: {
            'chai': '../node_modules/chai/chai.js',
            'chai-as-promised': '../node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js',
            // dependency of chai-as-promised
            'check-error': '../node_modules/check-error/check-error.js',
            'js-sha256': '../node_modules/js-sha256/build/sha256.min.js'
        }
    });

    Promise.all(
        mochaTestScripts.map(testScript =>
            SystemJS.import('./' + testScript + '-test.js')
            .catch(err => {
                const div = document.getElementById('errors');
                const pre = document.createElement('pre');
                pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test: ' + testScript + '\n\n' + err));
                div.appendChild(pre);
            })
        )
    )
    .then(() => {
        mocha.checkLeaks();
        mocha.globals([]);
        mocha.run();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        const div = document.getElementById('errors');
        const pre = document.createElement('pre');
        pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode('GLOBAL ERROR\n' + err));
        div.appendChild(pre);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it myself:**

I had to go to the source code of SystemJS to find the answer. The problem seems to be that the `SystemJS` symbol wasn't just a plain object like it normally is, where the methods are properties directly inside this object. Instead, `SystemJS` is an instance and the methods are on the prototype.

What finally worked was taken right from how SystemJS used `newModule` internally, and the final command that worked was

```
SystemJS.registry.set(
    'systemjs',
    SystemJS.newModule({default: SystemJS, __useDefault: true})
);
```

This replaces the line under `// THIS DOES NOT WORK:` in the above `index.html` test runner file.